# "Compile Error: Expected Array" when using Right function on a string

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet with a bunch of strings extracted from a text stored in various cells and I need to remove the last character from each of these strings if it is a comma or a dot.

I have been trying to iterate through the cells and use the Right function to check if the last character is a dot or a comma, but that is causing the error: "Compile Error: Expected Array".

```
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim cellValue As String
Dim wsFiltro2 As Worksheet

Set wsFiltro2 = Worksheets("SegundoFiltro")

For j = 1 To 10
    For i = 1 To 33
        cellValue = wsFiltro2.Cells(j, i).Value
        If right(cellValue, 1) = "," Or right(cellValue, 1) = "." Then
            wsFiltro2.Cells(j, i).Value = left(cellValue, Len(cellValue) - 1)
        End If
    Next i
Next j
```

EDIT: I originally had this loop inside another Sub that was first writing these strings to the sheet. When I tested this in a new Sub after writing the values it worked normally... Still don't get why it wasn't working inside the other Sub though

Comment: Which line of code is triggering the error?

Comment: @CindyMeister the line with the If statement. The debugger highlights the right function and shows the error message.

Comment: Looks like you have a global (or local but you did not show it) variable called `right` which makes `Right` function invisible.

Comment: Looks like there is also a variable/function callde `left`. Never ever name variables or functions with reserved key words! • Also note that row counting variables need to be of type `Long` Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle `Dim i As Long, j As Long`

Comment: @BrakNicku oh wow, you are absolutely correct! Totally missed that. Thank you and nice job figuring it out!